# How to display image in Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes

I am trying to display an image in a custom wordpress theme. In the theme folder I have an img folder with all the images. It does not show anything.

```
  <footer class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;"> 

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); 
           ?>/footer_logo.png"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) function to get URL of your active theme.

Here is the updated code, by which you can print image from your theme directory:

```
<footer class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;"> 

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/[img folder name]/footer_logo.png"></div> 
            </div>
</footer>
```

Let us know if you need any further help in this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am including the code you provided, but still the pciture does not appear. I am thinking, maybe the folder is not on the right place?

Comment: Let me know the folder structure of your img inside the theme, so that I can provide you accurate solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I forgot the backslash before the folder name. Thank you!

Comment: If my solution helps you, then can you please accept/upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to reference the image folder itself.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/footer_logo.png">
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the backslash before the folder name. Thank you!